# dbx: internal warning writable memory segment of size 0

Tags: debugging, solaris, coredump, dbx, core-file

While trying to load a core file using `dbx` I get the following warning:

```
dbx: internal warning: writable memory segment 0xfa8b0000[16384] of size 0 in core
```

There doesn't seem to be an explanation in:

```
(dbx) help core
```

What does this message mean?

**EDIT**

The rest of the output:

```
core file header read successfully
Reading ld.so.1

dbx: internal error: signal SIGBUS (invalid address alignment)
dbx's coredump will appear in /tmp
Abort (core dumped)
```

And dbx exits without loading the core.

Comment: Was the core file generated on the same machine ? Is the core file truncated for some reason ?

Comment: The core file was generated on the same machine. Not sure if it's truncated, the size is more than 400M. How do you tell?

Comment: Do you have issues with debugging using core file outside that warning message ?

Comment: I mean, using *this* core file.

Comment: Edited the question with more info

Comment: Seems like a bug in dbx.  You can try to open the core using mdb: `mdb core`

Comment: It does open with `mdb`, thanks for that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Got solved by upgrading Solaris Studio to version 12.3 and using the newer `dbx` from there.

Answer (score 0):

One of the reasons why this could happen is because dbx expects the absolute path to get the object files, try giving the

```
dbx <PATHTOBINARY>/binaryfile
```

Of course, you can upgrade dbx to the latest version to fix the same.